# Transfer UserForm textbox.value as date format to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

What i'm doing wrong. I want just to save my date from UserForm to the end of the list along with all other data. All works fine but i have problems with date format.

I use that macro to set it to "wanted" format in UserForm textbox:

```
Private Sub E1GExpiryDate_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim dDate As Date
  dDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
  E1GExpiryDate.Value = Format(E1GExpiryDate.Value, "mmm.yyyy")
dDate = E1GExpiryDate.Value
End Sub
```

And that macro to transfer it:

```
Private Sub SaveData()
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Tabelle1
  lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.E1GCharge.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.E1GMatName.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.E1Gtype.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.E1GMatNumber.Value
'copy date.........................
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Format(Me.E1GExpiryDate.Value, "mmm.yyyy")
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.E1GBoxPcs.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.E1GAmmount.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.E1GUnit.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.E1Gkonz.Value

End With
'Clear input controls.
  Me.E1GMatName.Value = ""
  Me.E1Gtype.Value = ""
  Me.E1GMatNumber.Value = ""
  Me.E1GExpiryDate.Value = ""
  Me.E1GBoxPcs.Value = ""
  Me.E1GAmmount.Value = ""
  Me.E1Gkonz.Value = ""
  Me.E1GUnit.Value = ""

Call GetData

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest letting Excel format it on the sheet instead of passing it as a `String`. You should generally store dates as `Date`, and only format them for displaying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))` is equivalent to `Date`.
2. But more importantly, *formatted-text-that-looks-like-a-date* (the result of `Format`) is not the same as an actual date (a numerical value) entered into a cell, which can then be formatted.
3. So write the `Date` into the cell and then change the cell's `NumberFormat`.

In your case:

```
....
.Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Date
.Cells(lRow, 6).NumberFormat = "mmm.yyyy"
....
```

Comment: How do you represent a month with three digits? Is it just a leading `0` every time?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 "mmm" is the shortened month name - "Jan", "Feb" and so on.

Comment: Ohh, that's cool I didn't realize you could do that. Thanks! I got thrown off by the `Number` part of `NumberFormat`